# Can't run dmidecode on docker container

Tags: linux, docker, containers

I am trying to run command dmidecode in my docker container,

```
docker run --device /dev/mem:/dev/mem -it jin/ubu1604
```

However, it claims that there is no permission

```
root@bd1062dfd8ab:/# dmidecode
# dmidecode 3.0
Scanning /dev/mem for entry point.
/dev/mem: Operation not permitted
root@bd1062dfd8ab:/# ls -l /dev
total 0
crw--w---- 1 root tty  136, 0 Jan  7 03:21 console
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     11 Jan  7 03:20 core -> /proc/kcore
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     13 Jan  7 03:20 fd -> /proc/self/fd
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root   1, 7 Jan  7 03:20 full
crw-r----- 1 root kmem   1, 1 Jan  7 03:20 mem
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root     40 Jan  7 03:20 mqueue
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root   1, 3 Jan  7 03:20 null
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      8 Jan  7 03:20 ptmx -> pts/ptmx
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      0 Jan  7 03:20 pts
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root   1, 8 Jan  7 03:20 random
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root     40 Jan  7 03:20 shm
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     15 Jan  7 03:20 stderr -> /proc/self/fd/2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     15 Jan  7 03:20 stdin -> /proc/self/fd/0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     15 Jan  7 03:20 stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root   5, 0 Jan  7 03:20 tty
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root   1, 9 Jan  7 03:20 urandom
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root   1, 5 Jan  7 03:20 zero
```

This confused me. Since I was able to run `dmidecode -t system` on the host (ubuntu 14.04) fine.

I even followed some advice and set the permission on dmidecode executable

```
setcap cap_sys_rawio+ep /usr/sbin/dmidecode
```

It still doesn't work.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Based on David Maze's answer, the command should be

```
run --device /dev/mem:/dev/mem --cap-add SYS_RAWIO -it my/ubu1604a
```

Do this only when you are going to trust what runs in container.  For example, if you are test installation procedure on a pristine OS.

Comment: Just what do you expect `dmidecode` to return on a docker container? Why would a container have a DMI (or SMBIOS)? (it's a table that contains a description of the system's **hardware** components)

Comment: I would like container to run ubuntu 16.04 and would like `dmidecode` to get the hardware info of the host from container. Don't mind the security issue in this case since I can trust the software running the container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Docker provides an isolation layer, and one of the major *goals* of Docker is to hide details of the host's hardware from containers.  The easiest, most appropriate way to query low-level details of the host's hardware is from a root shell on the host, ignoring Docker entirely.

The actual mechanism of this is by restricting Linux [capabilities](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html).  **capabilities**(7) documents that you need `CAP_SYS_RAWIO` to access `/dev/mem`, so in principle you can launch your container with `--cap-add SYS_RAWIO`.  You might need other capabilities and/or device access to make this actually work, because Docker is hiding the details of what you're trying to access as a design goal.