# dmidecode inside go program running in a kubernetes pod

Tags: linux, docker, go, kubernetes

I have a go routine running in docker container. I need output of the command dmidecode. But its coming blank.

Go:

func main() {

```
    cmd := exec.Command("dmidecode","-t 1")
    x,_ := cmd.Output()
    fmt.Println("output =======", string(x))
```

}

Docker run:

docker run --device /dev/mem:/dev/mem --cap-add SYS_RAWIO -p 8086:8086 -it my_img:1.0.1

What am I missing here?

**Updated:**

The above worked in docker after I added below in Dockerfile:

FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk --no-cache --update --verbose add grep bash dmidecode && 
rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* /tmp/* /sbin/halt /sbin/poweroff /sbin/reboot

And below in docker compose file:

privileged: true

**But When tried to use the above in kubernetes it not able to fetch demidecode output.**

A help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

> What am I missing here?

For starters ,error handling.

```
    x,_ := cmd.Output()
```

Never, ever ignore an error in Go.  Unlike languages like, say, Pyhton, there is no exception raising - handling error return values is your *only* chance to figure out if something went wrong.

Secondly, you're also ignoring your command's Standard Output stream. This is likely to contain a useful error message whenever a command execution doesn't work, so [`os/exec`'s `Output()` provides it as part of the error value](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Cmd.Output) if not already captured in the `Cmd` configuration.  Part of your error handling should be doing a [type assertion](https://go.dev/tour/methods/15) on that error value, if not nil, and if it's a valid `*exec.ExitError`, and if that type assertion succeeds, check [its Stderr field](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#ExitError) for an error message.

Third, looking at your command, I can see you made an easy mistake:

```
    cmd := exec.Command("dmidecode","-t 1")
```

At the *shell*, whitespace separates arguments.  but there is no shell here; you're passing `-t 1` all as one argument to `dmidecode`.  You should be passing them as *separate* arguments, almost certainly:

```
    cmd := exec.Command("dmidecode","-t", "1")
```

Finally, you've already found  [Can't run dmidecode on docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54068234/cant-run-dmidecode-on-docker-container/70084824#70084824) , but make sure to read and understand the accepted answer.  Then, get your docker container configured to be able to run `dmidecode` without Go.  Once it works at the command line, the same docker configuration should allow it to work under Go invocation as well.